# Mongodb recursive query

Tags: mongodb, recursion, aggregation-framework

I have the following schema in my `taxon` collection :

```
{ 
  "_id": 1, 
  "na": [ "root_1",
        "root_2",
        "root_3" ], 
  "pa": 1 
},{
  "_id": 2, 
  "na": [ "name_1", 
        "name_2", 
        "name_3"], 
  "pa": 1
},{
  "_id": 4, 
  "na": [ "otherName_1", 
        "otherName_2", 
        "otherName_3"],
  "pa": 2
}
```

Each document is related to another by the parent field, which correspond to the **`_id`** of it's parent.

I would like to perform a recursive search to get the following result:

```
{ "_id": 4, 
  "nameList": [ "otherName_1",
              "name_1",
              "root_1"]
}
```

From document with a certain **`_id`**, get the first item of **`na`** array of each parent until document with `_id: 1` is reached

I currently get this result by performing X queries (one by parent document, here 3 for example), but I'm pretty sure that this can be achieved using a single query. I already looked at the new [**$graphLookup**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) operator, but couldn't manage to get my way with it...

Is it possible to achieve this in a single query using MongoDB 3.4.1?

**Edit**

I would run this for 50 documents each time, so the optimal solution would be to combine everything in a single query

for example, it would looks like

```
var listId = [ 4, 128, 553, 2728, ...];
var cursor = db.taxon.aggregate([
  {$match: 
     { _id: {$in: listId}}
  }, ...
)];
```

and would output :

```
[{ "_id": 4, 
  "nameList": [ "otherName_1",
              "name_1",
              "root_1"]
}, { "_id": 128, 
  "nameList": [ "some_other_ame_1",
              "some_name_1",
              "root_1"]
}, { "_id": 553, 
  "nameList": [ "last_other_ame_1",
              "last_name_1",
              "root_1"]
} ... ]
```

try it online: [mongoplayground.net/p/Gfp-L03Ub0Y](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gfp-L03Ub0Y)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

Stages  `$match - $graphLookup - $project`.

`$reduce` to pick the first element from the each of `$graphLookup` `nameList's` `na` array.

```
db.taxon.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        _id: {
            $in: listId
        }
    }
}, {
    $graphLookup: {
        from: "taxon",
        startWith: "$_id",
        connectFromField: "pa",
        connectToField: "_id",
        as: "nameList"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        nameList: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$nameList",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                    "$concatArrays": ["$$value", {
                        $slice: ["$$this.na", 1]
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: this is a very nice solution, thanks a lot! Would it be possible for several documents in the same time ? (see my edit for details)

Comment: You are welcome. Updated answer. It should work with any matching condition.

Comment: Ok my bad I tried with $in but forgot to iterate over the cursor... This is exactly what I need, just need to run some performance test to see the actual gain! Do you have any advise on indexes for such a query ?